# How to split columns into two sub columns under their parent column using python in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, split

Need suggestion in python.
I have an excel sheet with 20 columns having values like 12-->23 i need to split all the columns into two pre and post where pre will have value 12 and post will have value 23 and so on ... and also these column should be exactly under their respective  parent column using pandas

Input:

```
| Column A | 
| -------- | 
| 12 --> 23|
| 13 --> 24|
```

Output

```
| column A |
|pre| |post|
| 12| | 23 |
| 13| | 24 |
```

There are lots of column so i can't  directly  use column name

I tried the following  code it worked if i know the column  name but not if i have to loop the columns without their name

```
df = pd.read_excel('path/to/excel_file.xlsx')

for col in df.columns:
    new_cols = df[col].str.split(expand=True)
    
    df[col + '_1'] = new_cols[0]
    df[col + '_2'] = new_cols[1]
df.drop(columns=df.columns[:-2], inplace=True)
```

It's  not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['pre', 'post']] = df['Column A'].str.split(r'\s*-->\s*', expand=True)
print(df)

# Output
    Column A pre post
0  12 --> 23  12   23
1  13 --> 24  13   24
```

So for multiple columns:

```
data = []

for col in df.columns:
    new_cols = df[col].str.split(r'\s*-->\s*', expand=True)
    if new_cols.shape[1] == 2:
        df = df.drop(columns=col)
        data.append(new_cols.add_prefix(col + '_'))
df = pd.concat([df, *data], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Column A_0 Column A_1
0         12         23
1         13         24
```